# GCP encryption thru Beam / Dataflow APIs for Bigquery and Cloud SQL

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

**Context:** We are trying to load some CSV format data into GCP BigQuery using GCP Dataflow (Apache Beam). As a part of this for the first time (for each table) creating the BQ tables thru BigQueryIO API. One of the customer requirement is the data on GCP needs to be encrypted using Customer supplied/managed Encryption keys.

**Problem Statement:** We are not able to find any way to specify the "Custom Encryption Keys" thru APIs while creating Tables. The GCP documentation details about how to specify the Custom encryption keys thru GCP BQ Console but could not find anything for specifying it thru APIs from within DataFlow Code.

**Code Snippet:**

```java
String tableSpec = new StringBuilder().append(PipelineConstants.PROJECT_ID).append(":")
    .append(dataValue.getKey().target_dataset).append(".").append(dataValue.getKey().target_table_name)
    .toString();

ValueProvider<String> valueProvider = StaticValueProvider.of("gs://bucket/folder/");

dataValue.getValue().apply(Count.globally()).apply(ParDo.of(new RowCount(dataValue.getKey())))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new SourceAudit(runId)));

dataValue.getValue().apply(ParDo.of(new PreProcessing(dataValue.getKey())))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new FixedToDelimited(dataValue.getKey())))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new CreateTableRow(dataValue.getKey(), runId, timeStamp)))
    .apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(tableSpec)
        .withSchema(CreateTableRow.getSchema(dataValue.getKey()))
        .withCustomGcsTempLocation(valueProvider)
        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

**Query:** If anybody could let us know

- If this is possible to provide encryption key thru Beam API?
- If its not possible with the current version what could be the possible work
  around?

Kindly let know if additional information is required.

Comment: This is a really new feature (still beta). The BigQuery client libs don't even support it, so Beam/Dataflow will not be able to support it yet. Will the tables be known in advance, or are they dynamic?

Comment: Related ... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-58?

Comment: @ Graham Polley, thanks for the response! the tables will be dynamic. As you mentioned I noticed the GCP documentation mentions BQ Client Lib don't support encryption settings.

Comment: @glytching, Thanks for the sharing the JIRA!

Comment: Would you need a separate encryption key per dynamic table, or one for all of them?

Comment: @ReuvenLax , The key can be one for all of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Customer supplied encryption keys is a new feature, not all libraries have been updated to support it yet.

If you know the table name in advance, you can use UI/CLI or API to create table, then run your normal flow to load data into that table. That might be a work around for you.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/customer-managed-encryption#create_table

API to create table: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert

You need to set this section on table object:
  "encryptionConfiguration": {
    "kmsKeyName": string
  }
More details on table: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#resource

Comment: Thanks for the response! The main issue is the tables are dynamic and not known beforehand. The work around you suggested is there but unfortunately that will not work  here. So effectively unless Google provides official support in lib seems no point in trying that. Waiting for the declaration. Thanks!

Comment: An updated client library for bigquery released a few days ago, now it has support for table encryption keys:https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/releases

Comment: thanks for the information! I will check this and will close the ticket accordingly.